# Using Protractor, failing test cases using maven and then maven build should fail or not?

Tags: maven, jenkins, protractor

Some of test cases are failed so due to that maven build is also failed .Just because of maven failure , Jenkins build is also failed.

So is it right or something is wrong in it?

Answer (score 0):

In your Jenkins job you *could* run Maven with either of the following parameters:

- `-DskipTests=true` to skip test execution entirely
- `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` to ignore test failures

**But** if the tests are important (and they certainly should be :) then perhaps ignoring them (or not running them) is the wrong approach, perhaps you should instead fix the failed tests.

Comment: Yeah those Test Case have major priority so Its good not to fix it through maven build success
Thank you for giving clarification on it

Comment: So u want to say that if test case are failing then Maven build has to be failed.
and that is a right approach.Is it so?